# Лучшее решение для чтения A и B из файла и вывод их суммы в файл

Tags: java, алгоритм, java-output-stream

Даны два числа A и B. Вам нужно вычислить их сумму A+B. В этой задаче вам нужно читать из файла и выводить ответ в файл. Первая строка входного файла содержит числа A и B (-2 ⋅ 109 ≤ A, B ≤ 2 ⋅ 109) разделенные пробелом. В единственной строке выходного файла выведите сумму чисел A+B. Но код который я посылаю не проходит проверку( Код ошибки: PE . Все это в Яндекс.Контест в тренировочном модуле задача 2), хотя в IntelliJ IDEA всё работает отлично. В чем может быть проблема?

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class B {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        int b = scanner.nextInt();


        writer.print(a+b);
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: В переполнении, вероятно... Если считываете и записываете верно (Java - не мой конек...)

Comment: там 2*109 или 2^109?

Comment: @Komdosh 2*10^9 же, разве не очевидно? :)

Comment: тогда попробуйте заменить на `nextLong`

Comment: Поменял на long, все равно Ошибка представления

Comment: Добавьте код ошибки в вопрос.

Comment: Добавил PE в описание

Answer (score 1):

у меня принял такой код:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class calc {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

    long result = 0;
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("input.txt")))
    {
        result = scanner.nextInt() + scanner.nextInt();
        //System.out.println(result);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"));
        pw.println(result);
        pw.close();}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема в выводе. Используйте `PrintWriter#println()`, чтобы вывести ответ

Comment: Окей :) не посмотрел на дату вопроса...